# Code file and header paths hard-coded in static library?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, filepath

I've opened a static library (compiled with VC++) in a hex editor and I see the paths of all code files and headers. I don't understand what purpose they serve there.
Is there a way to *not* have them embedded in the binary? I've been through all the options (I think) but couldn't find anything.

Comment: It's debug information. You can do a (release) build without this information.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/958x11bc.aspx

Comment: Forgot to say: it is a release build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the compiler embeds a lot of contextual information in a static library.  Keep in mind that a static lib is a pretty weak code abstraction, it is nothing but a bag of .obj files.  Think of it as a .zip file with a lousy compression ratio :)

There is a very hard requirement for that information, the rest of the tool-chain depends on it.  Like the library manager, it needs to merge the program databases.  And the linker, it needs to be able to restart the compiler's back-end to rebuild the binary with profile-guided optimization data.

Which is *probably* what you see, the /GL compile option embeds the command line that the compiler used.  So PGO can be properly done, using the exact same compile options.  Notable also for being *very* handy to the client programmer, he can reverse-engineer the compile options he needs to use to be able to properly link your library.  A very important detail that everybody forgets to document :)

Do note that you cannot reasonably remove this information, PGO is important.  If you don't like this kind of information disclosure then use a build server or ship a binary instead of a library.  A DLL.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, Hans. Now I get it.  Much appreciated :)